# SIM808 GNSS location update

Tags: gps, gnss

I'm working on a project in which I have to get the current location every 10 s. I've used a SIM808 (GSM/GPRS & GNSS) on which I execute the `AT+CGNSINF` command to get the location. I get the location string in a terminal using serial communication.

As I'm working with this device at my place, the SIM808 gives me complete data every 10 s with updated time and four satellites in view, and works fine as expected.

But when I go with my car to test the project, the SIM808 does not give me the updated data. It freezes at a position and gives me the old data every 10 s, even the time also. I don't know what the problem is. What should I do to make this thing work?

Comment: If your car has a metal roof, make sure that you put the device (or at least the antenna, if it's separate) on the dashboard, so that it has a clear view of the sky through the windshield. Better still, use an external magnetic-mount antenna and stick it to the roof.

Comment: how are you powering the module? What is the number of satellites in view before you move your car? where is the GPS antenna placed?

Answer (score 1):

That's just how GPS works. Once you've locked to a position, the internal routines will have it easier to keep your position correct. As soon as you start moving, things get more complicated for GPS receivers.

Now, walking from a flat to a car shouldn't be much of a challenge. Check your antenna, the surroundings (is this an urban scenario where you in the middle of building canyons that simply not allow for reception?) and whether you simply need a better receiver.